# MySQL - improve a heavy multiple child-nested queries query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join

I'm on a task to improve an app's DB query. This heaving-loading query takes roughly 3-5 minutes to complete which is unacceptable.

The previous developers built this query and they didn't do this job very well though. Now I'm having a bunch of child-queries in the main query which I have to improve. Looks like those child-queries are killing it.

Could anybody advise me which is the best approach to this?

```
SELECT
   `j`.`id`          AS          `job_id`,
   `j`.`job_number`          AS `job_number`,
   `j`.`job_status`          AS `job_status`,
   `j`.`job_registration_date`          AS `job_registered`,
   `j`.`created`          AS `job_created`,
   `q`.`quote_type_id`          AS `quote_type_id`,
   `qt`.`name`          AS `quote_type_name`,
   `q`.`created_by`          AS `consultant_id`,
   (SELECT
      Concat(`pr`.`first_name`,
      ' ',
      `pr`.`last_name`)           
   FROM
      `profiles` `pr`           
   WHERE
      (
         `pr`.`user_id` = `q`.`created_by` 
      ))          AS `consultant_name`,
   `q`.`domain_id`          AS `domain_id`,
   `p`.`id`          AS `package_id`,
   `q`.`id`          AS `quote_id`,
   `q`.`client_id`          AS `client_id`,
   Concat(`c`.`title`,
   ' ',
   `c`.`first_name`,
   ' ',
   `c`.`last_name`)          AS          `client_name`,
   `q`.`site_id`          AS `site_id`,
   `st`.`name`          AS `site_name`,
   Truncate(Abs(( `q`.`accepted_cost` / 1.1 )),
   2)          AS `est_sale`,

   Coalesce((SELECT
      Sum(`i`.`amount`)                    
   FROM
      `invoices` `i`                    
   WHERE
      ( ( `i`.`void` <> 1 )                             
      AND ( `i`.`job_id` = `j`.`id` ) )),
   (SELECT
      Sum(`i`.`amount`)           
   FROM
      `invoices` `i`           
   WHERE
      (          ( `i`.`void` <>            1 )          
      AND (          `i`.`job_id` = `j`.`id` ) )),
   0)          AS `actual_sale`,

   Coalesce((SELECT
      Sum(( `pp`.`qty` * `pp`.`unit_price` ))                    
   FROM
      `package_products` `pp`                    
   WHERE
      ( `pp`.`package_id` = `p`.`id` )),
   (SELECT
      Sum((          `pp`.`qty` * `pp`.`unit_price` ))           
   FROM
      `package_products` `pp`                                                               
   WHERE
      ( `pp`.`package_id`            = `p`.`id` )),
   0)                        AS `total_package_product`,

   Coalesce((SELECT
      Sum(( `ppt`.`qty` * `ppt`.`unit_price` ))                    
   FROM
      `package_parts` `ppt`                    
   WHERE
      ( `ppt`.`package_id` = `p`.`id` )),
   (SELECT
      Sum(( `ppt`.`qty` * `ppt`.`unit_price` ))           
   FROM
      `package_parts` `ppt`                                                                
   WHERE
      ( `ppt`.`package_id` = `p`.`id` )),
   0)          AS `total_package_part`,

   Coalesce((SELECT
      Truncate(Abs(Sum(( ( `lc`.`number_of_technician` *                                              `lc`.`hours` ) *   `lc`.`hours_rate` ))),
      2)   
   FROM
      `labour_costs` `lc`   
   WHERE
      ( `lc`.`package_id` = `p`.`id` )),
   (SELECT
      Truncate(   Abs(   Sum(( ( `lc`.`number_of_technician` *   `lc`.`hours` ) *   `lc`.`hours_rate` ))),
      2)   
   FROM
      `labour_costs` `lc`   
   WHERE
      ( `lc`.`package_id` = `p`.`id` )),
   0)                              AS          `total_labor_cost`,

   Coalesce((SELECT
      Sum(( `pmi`.`qty` * `pmi`.`cost` ))   
   FROM
      `package_misc_items` `pmi`   
   WHERE
      ( `pmi`.`package_id` = `p`.`id` )),
   (SELECT
      Sum(( `pmi`.`qty` * `pmi`.`cost` ))   
   FROM
      `package_misc_items` `pmi`    
   WHERE
      ( `pmi`.`package_id` = `p`.`id` )),
   0)                                    AS          `total_package_misc`,
   `p`.`discount`                                                            AS          `discount`,

   Coalesce((SELECT
      ( CASE   
         WHEN ( Sum(`jf`.`amount`) <> 0 ) THEN   Truncate(Abs(   Sum(`jf`.`amount`)),
         2)   
         ELSE NULL   
      end ) AS `acufile_amount`   
   FROM
      ((`acufiles` `a`   
   JOIN
      `acufile_categories` `c`   
         ON(( `c`.`id` = `a`.`category_id` )))   
   JOIN
      `job_files` `jf`   
         ON(( `jf`.`acufile_id` = `a`.`id` )))   
   WHERE
      ( ( `c`.`abbr` = 'CREDINV' )   
      AND ( `jf`.`job_id` = `j`.`id` ) )),
   0)                AS   `total_acufile_amount`,

   Coalesce((SELECT
      Truncate(Abs(Sum(( `ts`.`hours` *   `ef`.`e_total_hourly_rate` ))),
      2)   
   FROM
      ((`timesheet_entries` `ts`   
   JOIN
      `users` `u`   
         ON(( `ts`.`user_id` = `u`.`id` )))   
   JOIN
      `employee_financials` `ef`   
         ON(( `ef`.`user_id` = `u`.`id` )))   
   WHERE
      ( `ts`.`job_id` = `j`.`id` )),
   (SELECT
      Truncate(Abs(   Sum(( `ts`.`hours` *   `ef`.`e_total_hourly_rate` ))),
      2) AS   `e_total_labor_timecost`   
   FROM
      (   (`timesheet_entries` `ts`   
   JOIN
      `users` `u`   
         ON(( `ts`.`user_id` = `u`.`id` )))   
   JOIN
      `employee_financials` `ef`   
         ON(( `ef`.`user_id` = `u`.`id` )))   
   WHERE
      ( `ts`.`job_id` =        `j`.`id` )),
   0) AS   `total_labor_timecost`   
FROM
   (((((((`packages` `p`                 
JOIN
   `quote_options` `qo`                   
      ON(
         (
            `qo`.`id` = `p`.`quote_option_id` 
         )
      )
   )                
JOIN
`quotes` `q`                  
   ON(
      (
         `q`.`id` = `qo`.`quote_id` 
      )
   )
)               
JOIN
`quote_types` `qt`                 
ON(
   (
      `qt`.`id` = `q`.`quote_type_id` 
   )
)
)              
JOIN
`jobs` `j`                
ON(
(
   `q`.`id` = `j`.`quote_id` 
)
)
)             
JOIN
`contacts` `c`               
ON(
(
`c`.`id` = `q`.`client_id` 
)
)
)            
LEFT JOIN
`companies` `co`                   
ON(
(
`co`.`id` = `c`.`company_id` 
)
)
)           
LEFT JOIN
`sites` `st`                  
ON(
(
`q`.`site_id` = `st`.`id` 
)
)
)   
WHERE
(
`p`.`accepted` = 1 
)   
GROUP  BY
`p`.`id`
```

Comment: Looks like the site you actually want is [codereview \ mysql](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mysql). This probably isn't the right place for this.

Comment: I'm sure you will get better advice at the above link... and how I would begin is two-fold. One, make sure all indexes exist for all the child queries and joins and Two, start deconstructing it - meaning remove one piece (child query) at a time until you find the culprit(s). With luck it won't be evenly distributed. Even so, it'll give you a better picture what each piece is adding to your problem. In the process you will get to understand each piece better and, as Dan has advised, probably choose to rewrite the whole thing.

Comment: @DanBracuk okay thanks, the best answer ever. 1) don't get frustrated 2) do your work and do not ask.

Comment: Yeah that query looks uglier than sin.  Depending on how large the table is, it's probably far more efficient to scoop up batches of data and do the processing in a programming language.  Sometimes that's the best way to do it.  I see there's joins and inner selects of sums.  Much of that could probably be taken out or significantly reduced in comlexity, especially since sums and counts do not use indexes.  Inner selects can be real processing hogs too.